# List stored procedures based on specific word excluding comments

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to list out all the Stored Procedures (of a certain schema) contains 'EXEC' word. Here, I don't need Stored Procedures having commented "EXEC" word. I wrote below query but it gives me all the Stored Procedures i.e. Stored Procedures having "EXEC" in comments as well as "EXEC" in Stored Procedure body.

```
SELECT  s.name +'.'+P.name
FROM   sys.procedures P
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = P.schema_id
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%exec%'
and s.name like '%MySchema%'
```

Comment: You named the schema "EXEC"? I hope this was a good lesson for someone! :)

Comment: Nope. My Schema name is "MySchema" as I mentioned in the question. I'm searching for "EXEC" word in my Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

This will help but only if the comment is directly before it

```
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%exec%'
AND Object_definition(object_id) NOT LIKE '%-- exec%'
AND Object_definition(object_id) NOT LIKE '%/* exec%'
```